# How to get the Teams Unique ID based from "List chats" Graph API of the User who already interacted with the bot

Tags: c#, botframework, microsoft-teams, azure-ad-graph-api

We have installed bot for all the users, but we failed to capture Teams Unique ID for few users on the Conversation Update event. Is there a way to get the Teams Unique ID (29:***) for the users who have already chatted with the bot without any user interaction with the bot.  In this [Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/teams-proactive-messaging#get-the-chat-thread-id), says if you lose chat thread ID we can get again, but how to get the Teams Unique Id using Chat thread ID, So I can send the notification to those users.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

We don't have API to fetch user's 29 id without a conversation. There is API that can return a user's profile details but it has to be in conversation context.But, If You have teamId, you could [fetch the roster](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/bots/how-to/get-teams-context?tabs=dotnet) and get the channel account.